# Is there some way to "lock" page in case another user is editing - DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need some help. I got a page and I can switch it to another view where I got a form and I can change some texts on that page and save it. Is there any way how to lock/hide button if some user is editing, so another user can not access the editing form page and is only allowed to see the "view" of the page. I want to implement, so two users will not be able to edit page at the same time.

I was trying to find something on the internet but I did not found anything useful for DJANGO.

Thanks a lot for some recommendation how to do it.

Comment: How will it be unlocked if user 1 (let's forget about race conditions for a moment) never stops editing or submits anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a foreign key on the model that's mapped to a user. Then you would set that field to a user when they browse to the edit page.

You'd need to do it as follows.

```
has_lock = Page.objects.filter(id=page_id).filter(
    Q(editing_user__isnull=True)
    | Q(editing_user=request.user)
).update(editing_user=request.user)
if not has_lock:
    # Do something here to when another user is editing the page.
    # Raise 404, message the user and redirect, it's up to you.
# continue the editing view flow.
```

If you do go this route, you'll also need to handle unsetting that value and expiring it.